# Weird behaviour with arrays in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, removeall

I am facing issue with a piece of code, with slight modification I am getting different results which should not be the case.

Version 1 is giving the correct results, I am facing issue with Version 2 which is the actual code.

**Version 1:**

```
<cfset keywords = listToArray("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10")>

<!--- Common Code Below --->
<cfoutput>#getMetadata(keywords).getName()#</cfoutput>

<cfset toBeAdded = keywords>
<cfset toBeInactivated = listToArray("1,3,4,6,8")>
<cfset toBeActivated = toBeInactivated>

<cfset toBeAdded.removeAll(toBeInactivated)>
<cfset toBeInactivated.removeAll(keywords)>
<cfset toBeActivated.retainAll(keywords)>
```

**Version 2:**

```
<cfset keywords = []>
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter">
    <cfset arrayAppend( keywords, counter )>
</cfloop>

<!--- If I add following line here then it is working as expected and similar to version 1:  --->
<!--- <cfset keywords = listToArray(arrayToList(keywords))> --->

<!--- Common Code Below --->
<cfoutput>#getMetadata(keywords).getName()#</cfoutput>

<cfset toBeAdded = keywords>
<cfset toBeInactivated = listToArray("1,3,4,6,8")>
<cfset toBeActivated = toBeInactivated>

<cfset toBeAdded.removeAll(toBeInactivated)>
<cfset toBeInactivated.removeAll(keywords)>
<cfset toBeActivated.retainAll(keywords)>
```

**Outputs:**

[image][image]

Here are the gists: [`Version 1`](https://trycf.com/gist/891b8c4ee9d4ff62bbf4a6bc3d2ff285/acf11?theme=monokai) and [`Version 2`](https://trycf.com/gist/9701427f09cf064153f39ca31cd0086d/acf11?theme=monokai).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no Java guy but from what I can tell...

In Version 1: `keywords` contains `java.lang.String` values and in Version 2: `keywords` contains `java.lang.Double` values.

In Version 2: `toBeInactivated` contains strings values to be removed from the array of doubles.

Since those Java types do not match, they won't be removed from the collection properly. I'm guessing when CF passes the underlying object data around, it's never casted correctly. Which honestly I'd expect when everything is typeless to CF.

*Adding on from the comment by @Twillen below, this works when you cast `counter` to a type of `java.lang.String`:*

```
<cfset keywords = []>
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter">
    <cfset arrayAppend( keywords, javaCast("string", counter) )>
</cfloop>


<!--- Common Code Below --->
<cfoutput>#getMetadata(keywords).getName()#</cfoutput>

<cfset toBeAdded = keywords>
<cfset toBeInactivated = listToArray("1,3,4,6,8")>
<cfset toBeActivated = toBeInactivated>

<cfset toBeAdded.removeAll(toBeInactivated)>
<cfset toBeInactivated.removeAll(keywords)>
<cfset toBeActivated.retainAll(keywords)>

<cfdump var="#toBeAdded#" label="To Be Added">
<cfdump var="#toBeInactivated#" label="To Be Inactivated">
<cfdump var="#toBeActivated#" label="To Be Activated">
```

Comment: You completed your answer before I completed mine. The only thing I'd add is you can get versin two to match version one by casting the values to string with `arrayAppend( keywords, JavaCast("String", counter)`.

Comment: Ah, that didn't strike me. Thanks :)

Comment: "Which honestly I'd expect when everything is typeless to CF." True, but only with CF methods. Dumping the object shows removeAll() and retainAll() aren't implemented by CF. It's inherited from java's Vector, so no special CF handling. You get whatever rules Vector applies to collections. https://pastebin.com/8DjrtFEE

Answer (score 0):

A ColdFusion array isn't a Java Collection object. So I question the use of removeAll() and retainAll() with such arrays. Bearing that in mind, my answer is:

```
<cfset keywords = createobject("java","java.util.Vector").init()>
<cfset toBeAdded = createobject("java","java.util.Vector").init()>
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="counter">
    <cfset keywords.add(javaCast("int", counter))>
    <cfset toBeAdded.add(javaCast("int", counter))>
</cfloop>

<!--- Common Code Below --->
<cfoutput>#getMetadata(keywords).getName()#</cfoutput>

<cfset listToBeInactivated = "1,3,4,6,8">
<cfset toBeInactivated = createobject("java","java.util.Vector").init()>
<cfset toBeActivated = createobject("java","java.util.Vector").init()>
<cfloop list="#listToBeInactivated#" index="index">
    <cfset toBeInactivated.add(javaCast("int", index))>
    <cfset toBeActivated.add(javaCast("int", index))>
</cfloop>

<cfset toBeAdded.removeAll(toBeInactivated)>
<cfset toBeInactivated.removeAll(keywords)>
<cfset toBeActivated.retainAll(keywords)>

<cfdump var="#toBeAdded#" label="toBeAdded">
<cfdump var="#toBeInactivated#" label="toBeInactivated">
<cfdump var="#toBeActivated#" label="toBeActivated">
```